# Discontinuous function that has an antiderivative (Pugh, Exercise 3.40)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm having some trouble with a problem from Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis* (Exercise 3.40). The problem is as follows:

Set $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x \le 0 \\ \sin{\frac{\pi}{x}} & \text { if } x > 0\end{cases} ~~~~ \text{ and } ~~~~g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x \le 0 \\ 1 & \text{ if } x >0 \end{cases}$$
Prove that $f$ has an antiderivative while $g$ does not.

I've shown that $g$ has no antiderivative since if it did, $G'(0)=g(0)=0$. By the antiderivative theorem, $$G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)dt+C$$ so for $x \le 0$, $G(x)=C$ and for $x > 0$, $G(x)=x+C$. Since $G(0)=C$, we have $$\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{h}(G(h)-G(0))=\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{h}(C-C)=\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{0}{h}=0$$
The positive case on the other hand has $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}(G(h)-G(0))=\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}(h)=1$$ so $G'(0)$ can not exist.

I've tried setting $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt$ and clearly by the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, $F'(x)=f(x)$ $\forall{x} \ne 0$ since $f$ is discontinuous only at $0$. I'm failing to show however that $F'(0)=0$ which would be required for $F$ to be an antiderivative. I'm trying to show that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}f(t)dt=0$$ and this is obvious in the $h \to 0^{-}$ direction but I'm unable to show this for $h \to 0^{+}$. L'Hopital doesn't work since $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \sin\frac{\pi}{h}$ is undefined, but I'm not really sure how else to show $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{h} \int_{0}^{h}\sin\frac{\pi}{x}dx=0$$

Any help would be appreciated.